# Date format - Swift

Tags: ios, date, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I need to find the date format for this type of date:

2013-01-02T16:19:56.000000

I have tried a few such as yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.SSS with no luck

If you can tell me which one that would be great,

Thanks

Comment: That's 24-hour (as noted by the "16" hour). Use HH instead of hh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be like this if you want to skip all the 0: `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss`

The ISO standard format is `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'`